# Avoiding multiple type parameters

Tags: c#

Short version:

How can I best avoid using multiple type parameters? According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182129.aspx) it is a bad idea.

Long version:

I have 3 interfaces. I have multiple classes implementing these interfaces. It looks something like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface1 { }
public interface IMyInterface2 { }
public interface IMyInterface3 { }

public class MyClass1A : IMyInterface1 { public int Id { get; set; } }
public class MyClass1B : IMyInterface1 { }
public class MyClass1C : IMyInterface1 { }

public class MyClass2A : IMyInterface2 { }
public class MyClass2B : IMyInterface2 { }
public class MyClass2C : IMyInterface2 { }

public class MyClass3A : IMyInterface3 { }
public class MyClass3B : IMyInterface3 { }
public class MyClass3C : IMyInterface3 { }
```

Originally I had a base class and a class that derives from it with multiple type parameters like this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T, U, V>
    where T : IMyInterface1
    where U : IMyInterface2
    where V : IMyInterface3
{
    public T ConcreteMyInterface1 { get; set; }
    public U ConcreteMyInterface2 { get; set; }
    public V ConcreteMyInterface3 { get; set; }

    public abstract T DoStuffWithInterface1();
}

public class MyClass : MyBaseClass<MyClass1A, MyClass2A, MyClass3A>
{
    public override MyClass1A DoStuffWithInterface1()
    {
        var id = ConcreteMyInterface1.Id;
        return ConcreteMyInterface1;
    }
}
```

In an effort to remove the type parameters I refactored the code but it resulted in me having to cast everywhere like this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public IMyInterface1 ConcreteMyInterface1 { get; set; }
    public IMyInterface2 ConcreteMyInterface2 { get; set; }
    public IMyInterface3 ConcreteMyInterface3 { get; set; }

    public abstract IMyInterface1 DoStuffWithInterface1();
}

public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        ConcreteMyInterface1 = new MyClass1A();
        ConcreteMyInterface2 = new MyClass2A();
        ConcreteMyInterface3 = new MyClass3A();
    }

    public override IMyInterface1 DoStuffWithInterface1()
    {
        var id = ((MyClass1A)ConcreteMyInterface1).Id;
        return ConcreteMyInterface1;
    }
}
```

I was hoping for something more helpful than what Microsoft had to say in the above linked article:

`To fix a violation of this rule, change the design to use no more than two type parameters.`

Comment: I think you are spending too much time worrying about robotically generated code-style suggestions.  Even the MSDN explanation for why they should be avoided seems off to me: `TooManyTypeParameters<T, K, V>` -- yes, `T`, `K`, and `V` sure is confusing, but that's why the type parameters should not be named with single characters (at least when more than one).  The better reason is that they are cumbersome to use, because passing around the type becomes increasingly inconvenient.  That being said, sometimes three type parameters is exactly right.  It entirely depends on the given scenario.

Comment: (As a comparison, `Action<,,,,,,,,>` has nine type parameters; sometimes your scenario might be analogous and similarly justified -- or not)